# How CallSuper annotation evaluates whether overridden method is calling the super method or not?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I just found curious how my andorid studio is able to notify me when in my `onCreate()` method of Activity when I fail to call `super.onCreate()` then came to know that Android (too smart) implemented annotation `CallSuper` to make sure that the overridden method is calling the super method.

I just went into `CallSuper` to see the magic of what's happening internally,

```
package androidx.annotation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.CLASS;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Denotes that any overriding methods should invoke this method as well.
 * <p>
 * Example:
 * <pre><code>
 *  &#64;CallSuper
 *  public abstract void onFocusLost();
 * </code></pre>
 */
@Documented
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface CallSuper {
}
```

Source code reference : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/annotation/CallSuper.java
But to my surprise it does nothing. Where does it evaluate the method against this annotation? How compiler is able to do that? I'm quite curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works via a lint rule bundled into the android developer tools.

It's not just the [`@CallSuper`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:annotation/annotation/src/main/java/androidx/annotation/CallSuper.java)  annotation acting alone. The annotation works as an identifier for the accompanying lint rule. Check out the source of the [`CallSuperDetector`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:tools/base/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/CallSuperDetector.java).